# error with bucketing with clusters in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
DROP TABLE filtered_online_march_customers;
            --creating bucketed table with customer id
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filtered_online_march_customers(
              customer_id           string,
              order_id              string
            )
            CLUSTERED BY(customer_id) INTO 32 BUCKETS;

--populating the table
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
FROM filtered_march_online_transactions
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE filtered_online_march_customers
SELECT
  *
```

I created this table that clusters by customer_id. However when I actually try to use the buckets it does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE randomized_filtered_march_customers
AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
 filtered_online_march_customers
TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 32 ON customer_id)
```

I got the error:
 cannot find dir = maprfs:///hive/v0k0020.db/filtered_online_march_customers/000000_0 in pathToPartitionInfo: [maprfs:/hive/v0k0020.db/filtered_online_march_customers/000000_0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getPartitionDescFromPathRecursively(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getPartitionDescFromPathRecursively(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat$CombineHiveInputSplit.(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1090)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:931)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:882)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(cannot find dir = maprfs:///hive/v0k0020.db/filtered_online_march_customers/000000_0 in pathToPartitionInfo: [maprfs:/hive/v0k0020.db/filtered_online_march_customers/000000_0])'

If I change the query to

```
CREATE TABLE randomized_filtered_march_customers
    AS
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
     filtered_online_march_customers
    TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 32 ON rand())
```

It works fine. Any idea how to address it?

Comment: could you add some sample data? insert scripts with hardcoded values, hard to replicate without that

Comment: C95CDD369D454C1894 (customer_id)        358176503325(order_id).